# Maintainability of TFS xaml build vs TFS vNext build vs Octopus Deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy, vnext, xamlbuild

My question is about maintainability of vNext/Octopus processes vs XAML based processes. Or rather about the impossibility to maintain them sanely leading me to believe we are doing something terribly wrong.

Given:

- Microsoft pushes to phase out its TFS XAML builds in favour of the vNext builds
- Octopus Deploy is a popular deployment automation framework
- We have many XAML based builds, but starting to port to vNext
- The deployments are automated with Octopus Deploy

Concretely, we have three kinds of builds going on in QA:

- **Old XAML based compilation builds** producing artifacts to be deployed

  - Ultimately just builds the code, zips it and places in a well-known location
- **New vNext compilation builds** producing artifacts to be deployed

  - Same as above
- **Deployment builds**

  1. XAML based build definition per deployment environment. This is the source of truth for the particular deployment, containing all the configuration URLs, connection strings, certificate thumbprints, etc.. The build definition has over 100 build parameters. Each time a new environment is setup we clone an existing XAML build definition and change the parameters.

     - This build unpacks the build artifact, generates all the web/app config files based on the configuration parameters and kicks off Octopus Deploy with a lot of parameters using octo.exe and waiting for the end
  2. Octopus Deploy process

     - Creates 3 packages from the build artifact previously unpacked by the XAML build to match three areas of deployment - web farm, background job engine cluster and the database
     - Delivers the relevant packages to the relevant tentacles.
     - The tentacles unpack and setup their respective packages

So, if we have 50 deployment environments, then we have 50 XAML deployment builds, each capturing the context of the respective environment. But the XAML deployment build delegates the deployment job to Octopus and **here we are forced to have 50 Octopus projects - one per deployment.**

Why is it so? We examined the option of having just one Octopus Project, but what would be the Release versions of such project? In order for us to be able to navigate amongst the gazillion releases, the release version must include:

- The build version of the deployed code, e.g. `55.0.18709.3`
- The name of the deployment environment, e.g. `atwfm`

Using the example above this gives us `55.0.18709.3-atwfm`, but sometimes we want to deploy the same build artifact in the same deployment environment twice. But the only Octopus project would already have the release `55.0.18709.3-atwfm`, so how to deploy `55.0.18709.3` in `atwfm` again, without deleting the already existing release?

We could not find a workaround and so, we have Octopus project per deployment.

**THIS IS ABSOLUTELY CRAZY** because Octopus projects are a pain to update. Suppose we need to add a step - go do it in 50 projects. There are great advises on the Internet to use automation to edit multiple projects. Not ideal at all.

vNext, BTW, has the same problem. If I am to port the existing XAML builds to vNext I will end up with 50 vNext deployment builds. If I decide to add a step, I need to do it in all the 50 builds!!!

Note, that XAML builds do not have this problem (they have many others, though), because their the process is separate from the parameters. I can modify the workflow once and all the XAML builds are now updated with the new process change.

My question is - how do people work with vNext and Octopus, because our process drives me crazy. There must be a better way.

**EDIT 1**

I would like to clarify. **We sometimes want to deploy the same build artifacts twice**. We are not recompiling them and reusing the same version. No. We already have the build artifacts handy with the build version baked inside the artifact. We may want to deploy it the second time into the same environment because, for example, some databases in that environment have been misconfigured and now this is fixed and we need to redeploy. This does not mean we can rerun the already existing Octopus release, because the fix may involve tweaking the deployment parameters of the respective XAML deployment build definition. Hence we may be forced to restart the XAML deployment build, which never compiles code.

**EDIT 2**

First of all, why do we drive the deployment from TFS XAML builds rather than from Octopus? Historic reasons. We did not have Octopus at first. The deployment was done by our ad hoc code. When we introduced Octopus we decided to keep the XAML deploymenet builds for two reasons:

1. To save the cost of migrating all the XAML deployment builds with all the gazillion deployment parameters to Octopus. Maybe it was a wrong decision, maybe we could have automated the migration.
2. Because TFS has better facility to display test results. The deployment may end with deployment smoke tests and their results has to be published somewhere. We do not see how Octopus can help us publish the results, TFS can.

Why would one redeploy? For example, one of the deployment parameters is certificate thumbprint. When the certificate is renewed, this parameter must be changed (we do have automation for updating XAML build parameters). But often we discover that it was already deployed with wrong thumbprint. So, we fix the deployment and redeploy. Or, we discover some strange behavior of the deployed application and wish to redeploy with some extra tracing/debugging features.

Comment: A possible solution is to build packages only once and to do that you have to find a way to decouple environment specific configuration settings from your build process and inject environment configuration at deployment time.
(https://12factor.net/config)
(https://continuousdelivery.com/implementing/patterns/)

Comment: I don't think the edit changes my answer, you can re-deploy the same release many times as you like. what you cannot do is create a new release with the same version number. You might want to decouple these steps could you add some more detail about what changes in the XAML build? You can [change variables in a release](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/5130-how-to-update-a-single-variable-in-an-existing-release), you can update them in octopus and then redeploy

Comment: Added **EDIT 2**

Comment: And the reason for a close vote is ... ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot to unpack here, but I'll give it a go.

TL;DR It's the way you version the releases that's causing you all the pain. Change that and everything else will fall in to place

Lets start at the end and work backwards.

Octopus Deploy has a concept of Environments. This means that you can Deploy the same project to multiple environments and use Octopus's scoping mechanism to manage environment specific configuration.

So using your example.

> Creates 3 packages from the build artifact previously unpacked by the
>   XAML build to match three areas of deployment - web farm, background
>   job engine cluster and the database

I set up an Environment in Octopus for each of your 50 Environments. (I'll use 3 environments in the example to keep it simple, but the principles apply no matter how many environments you have)

In my Dev Environment I have a single server so I create an environment called "Dev" and add the tentacle for that specific server. Then I tag the tentacle with the deployment type "Web", "Job", "Database"

I then set up a test environment which has 3 servers so I create the Environment and add the 3 servers. I then tag each tentacle with the deployment type "Web", "Job", "Database"

Finally I set up the Production environment. This has 5 web servers, 1 job server and 1 database server. I add all 7 tentacles to the environment, and tag them appropriately.

Now I only need 1 project to deploy to all 3 environments. In my project I have 3 steps.

Step 1 Deploy Web Site

Step 2 Deploy Jobs

Step 3 Deploy database

I can tag each of these steps to say what kind of tentacle I want to deploy to. Now when I run the deployment the link between the tags on the step, and the tags on the tentacle mean Octopus knows where to deploy the code.

**Variables:** Your variables can be scoped to an environment. So for example if your dev environment database connection string is `dev.database.net/Instance` and your test environment database connection string is `test.Database.net/Instance` then you can scope these in the variables section of the project. If your DNS is consitant with your environment names you could even use some of the built in variables to make adding environments more easy. i.e. `${Octopus.Environment.Name}.Database.net/Instance`

**Releases and version numbers:** *So here is where I think your problem lies.* Adding the environment name to the release and trying to create multiple releases with the same version is basically causing you all of the pain.

> Using the example above this gives us 55.0.18709.3-atwfm, but
>   sometimes we want to deploy the same build artifact in the same
>   deployment environment twice. But the only Octopus project would
>   already have the release 55.0.18709.3-atwfm, so how to deploy
>   55.0.18709.3 in atwfm again, without deleting the already existing release?

There are a couple of things here. In Octopus you can easily deploy again from the UI, however it sounds like you're rebuilding the artifact and trying to create a new release with the same version number. Don't do this! Each new build should have a distinct and unique build number / release number.

The principle I follow is "build once deploy many"

When you create a release it requires a version number, this release then flows through the environments. So I build my code and it gets a versions number `55.0.18709.3` then I deploy it to Dev. When the deployment has been verified I then want to "Promote" the release to test I can do this from within Octopus or I can get TFS to do this.

So I promote `55.0.18709.3` to test and then on to prod. If I need to know which release is in which environment, Octopus tells me this via the dashboard or API.

Finally I can "Orchestrate" the flow of releases through my environments using Build v.next.

So my end to end process looks something like.

Build vNext Build

- Compile
- Run Unit Tests
- Package output
- Publish package

build vNext Release

- Call Octopus to create the release passing in the version number
- Optionally deploy the release to the first environment on your way to live

I now have everything I need in Octopus to deploy to ANY environment with a single project and my environment specific configuration.

I can either "Deploy" the release to a specific environment or "Promote" the release from one environment to another. This can be done easily from within the Octopus UI

Or I can create a "Promote" using the Octopus plugin in TFS and use that to orchestrate the promotion of code through the environments.

Octopus Terminology.
Create release - This pulls together the Artifacts and Release number in Octopus to create an Immutable thing which will be deployed to one of more environments.

Deploy release - The act of pushing your code to a specific environment.

Promote release - Once the code has been deployed in to a single environment, it can them be promoted in to other environments

If you have a specific sequence of environments then you can use the "Lifecycles" feature of Octopus to enforce that workflow. but that's a topic for another day!

**EDIT1 Response**

I don't think the edit changes my answer, you can re-deploy the same release many times as you like. what you cannot do is create a new release with the same version number. You might want to decouple these steps could you add some more detail about what changes in the XAML build? You can change variables in a release, you can update them in octopus and then redeploy

**EDIT 2 Response**

That makes things clearer. I think you need to take the hit and migrate the parameters to Octopus. It's variable management is much better than XAML builds and although build vNext is comparable to Octopus it makes more sense to have the config in Octopus. As XAML builds are on their way out, it makes sense to move this stuff now. Whilst it might be a lot of work, at the end you'll have a much smother workflow and you can really take advantage of the power of Octopus.

The Test results point. I agree this is better suited to build vNext, so at this point you will be using build vNext as your Orchestrator and Octopus Deploy as your release management tool.

The process would look something like

Build vNext

- Compile code.
- Run Unit tests
- Run Octopack
- Publish packages
- Call Octopus and Create release
- Call Octopus to Deploy to "Dev"
- Run Smoke tests
- Run Integration Tests
- Call "Selenium" to run Run UI tests
- Call Octopus to Promote release to "Test"
- Run Smoke tests
- Run Integration Tests
- Call "Selenium" to run Run UI tests
- Call Octopus to Promote release to "Production" (Perhaps with a manual  innervation)
- Run Smoke tests
- Run Integration Tests
- Call "Selenium" to run Run UI tests

Comment: +1 for taking the time. Thank you. I have just added **EDIT 1** to clarify something that may affect your answer. Would you be able to review and change it accordingly?